# Sympy and matrix differential ODE

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

How can I use Sympy to solve a matrix differential equation?

I have an equation of the form y'(t) = A*y(t) + B, where A is a 3x3 matrix, y(t) is a 1x3 vector, and B is a 1x3 vector.

More specifically, I'm working on a computer graphics problem that uses a differential equation to move points in 3D. I have a point in 3D space y(t), a 3x3 rotation matrix, and a translation vector. The y'=Ay+B equation is a simplification of the real problem I'm working on, but I've been unable to use Sympy to solve even y'=Ay+B. I am looking for the closed-form solution (not the numerical answer) in Sympy.

I know how to solve the equation y'=Ay+B, but I want to use Sympy to find the same solution, and then adapt the code to the more complex problem I'm trying to solve.

My current code is this:

```
from sympy import *

y0 = Function('y0')
y1 = Function('y1')
y2 = Function('y2')
t = symbols(('t'))
b0,b1,b2 = symbols(('b0:3'))

y = Matrix([y0(t), y1(t), y2(t)])
B = Matrix([b0,b1,b2])

ode = Eq(y.diff(t), y)

soln = dsolve(ode, y0(t),y1(t),y2(t))
```

but that causes the Python error

```
TypeError: cannot add <class 'sympy.matrices.immutable.ImmutableDenseMatrix'> and <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Dummy'>
```

In the above example, it's using the even more simplified example of y'=y+B, but even that's not working.

What's the best way to set problems like this up in Sympy?

Answer (score 0):

`dsolve` expects flat lists or flat tuples, not matrices. To convert a column matrix A into  a flat list, one can use the incantation `A.T.tolist()[0]` - that is, transpose, turn into a nested list `[[x, y, z]]`, then take the 0th entry `[x, y, z]`. So, your code should be

```
ode = (y.diff(t) - y).T.tolist()[0]
soln = dsolve(ode, y.T.tolist()[0])
```

It is usually more convenient to pass the difference `lhs-rhs` instead of `Eq(lhs, rhs)`, so I did that.

Sadly, the output is

```
[Eq(y0(t), C1*exp(t)), False, False]
```

(in both 1.1.1 and 1.2), which is obviously a bug. The solution of linear ODE systems with more than two equations in SymPy is currently based on some college student's misunderstanding of an ODE course they took. [This PR](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/14445) would fix most of those issues but it's abandoned.